# Why I dont's see colors in object mode?

Tags: color

Why I don’t see colors in object mode on my donut? If I take for example render mode or shading mode, I see them. Moreover if I turn new file blender on and paint cube, I see colors in object mode normally. What’s the matter?[image] [image]

Comment: Can you put an image of view port shading?

Answer (score 2):

You are in solid viewport shading mode.

Look at the header of the 3D View and [locate the four spheres](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/introduction.html#display-shading). There you can change the [viewport shading mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/shading.html?highlight=solid#viewport-shading).

When you are in [Solid](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/shading.html?highlight=solid#solid) shading mode, the color in the 3D viewport is from the materials [Viewport Display > Color](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/materials/settings.html#viewport-display). When you are **not** using nodes (as with your red cube), then the material's *Base Color* is the same as the *Viewport Display > Color*.

[image: no nodes]

However, when you activate nodes, the rendering settings (defined in the nodes) and the *Viewport Display* settings are not synchronized anymore.

[image: with nodes]

To preview the material settings and material nodes, switch the viewport to [material preview](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/shading.html#material-preview) by clicking on the third sphere in the header of the 3D viewport.

[image: material preview]